# Why won't Firefox execute JavaScript code after a download button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an HTML table of common programs people download - like Chrome and Dropbox for a couple - as sort of an expediting and useful portal. When the ASP.NET download `ImageButton` is clicked, I have a JavaScript function that makes an `XMLHttpRequest` that monitors the download progress of the .exe and gives a status message. I call the JavaScript function from the `OnClientClick` property of the ASP.NET `ImageButton`, and then the code-behind C# does the actual downloading from `OnClick`. The download progress bar and status message work just fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. The table is on the URL https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Random. Last time I checked, Firefox does support XMLHttpRequests.

I've tried using anchor (`a`) tags with the `href` as the download URL and `onclick` as the JavaScript function in place of the ImageButton and the C# downloading code, but still get the download popup to appear with no progress or message appearing on my page.

HTML:

```
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px"><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton7" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Download('Executables/readerdc_en_ka_cra_install.exe', 'ImageButton7', 'Loading3', '#save-file3', '#progressBar3', 'result4', 'blob');" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadButton.PNG" Height="38px" OnCommand="GetFileEXE" CommandArgument="Executables/readerdc_en_ka_cra_install.exe" /><button class="buttonload" id="Loading3"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Loading</button></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px"><div id="progressBar3" class="progressBar"><div></div></div></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px"><p id="result4">Message: </p></td>
          <td><a id="save-file3" href="#">Save to PC</a>&nbsp;<div class="g-savetodrive" data-src="Executables/readerdc_en_ka_cra_install.exe" data-filename="Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" data-sitename="Max's Tech and Math Site"></div></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script>
        function progress(percent, $element) {
            var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
            //$element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
            $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 100).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
        }

        function Download(file_name, download_button, load_button, save_link, progress_bar, result, response_type) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (e) {
                if (request.readyState === 2 && request.status === 200) {
                    // Download is being started
                    document.getElementById(download_button).style = "display: none; visibility: hidden";
                    document.getElementById(load_button).style = "display: block; visibility: visible";
                }
                else if (request.readyState === 3) {
                    // Download is under progress
                }
                else if (request.readyState === 4) {
                    // Downloading has finished
                    document.getElementById(download_button).style = "display: block; height: 38px; visibility: visible";
                    document.getElementById(load_button).style = "display: none; visibility: hidden";
                    document.querySelector(save_link).setAttribute('href', _OBJECT_URL);
                    document.querySelector(save_link).setAttribute('download', file_name);
                    _OBJECT_URL = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
                    // Recommended : Revoke the object URL after some time to free up resources
                    // There is no way to find out whether user finished downloading
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);
                    }, 60 * 1000);
                }
            });
            request.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    progress(percent_complete, $(progress_bar));
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(result).innerHTML += "Length of file is not computable.";
                }
            });
            request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
            request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
            request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);
            request.open('get', file_name);
            request.responseType = response_type;
            request.send();
            function transferComplete(evt) {
                document.getElementById(result).innerHTML += "The transfer is complete.";
            }

            function transferFailed(evt) {
                document.getElementById(result).innerHTML += "An error occurred while transferring the file.";
            }

            function transferCanceled(evt) {
                document.getElementById(result).innerHTML += "The transfer has been canceled by the user.";
            }
            return true;
        }
     </script>
```

C# (this code shouldn't be the issue):

```
    protected void GetFileEXE(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string file = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        string filename = Server.MapPath(file);
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-msdownload";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Might be a security problem. Maybe Firefox doesn't support AJAX to download files to disk. So when the code detects this case, it just sends the URL to the standard download code and cancels the request.

Comment: the page you listed is utterly broken - try again after you fix the [HTML errors](https://validator.nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fmaxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net%2FRandom) first

Comment: Aaron Digulla - I tried getting rid of the C# function to download files to disk while keeping JavaScript, but still nothing happens and now there is a postback and the page reloads since I'm using Web Forms and not MVC. In Chrome, the postback also happens and this time the download progress and message don't work since there is no download to monitor. AJAX is async so maybe that's why they don't work same time. birdspider - a majority of those errors were from CSS linting, like with some obsolete properties. I can fine-tune my page a little, but I don't think any of the errors are the issue.

Comment: I should have thought that without an `OnClick` property (or in my case, `OnCommand`) for an ASP.NET button, a postback with empty output would occur - however I still had `UseSubmitBehavior` set to `false`. I'll keep researching this problem and keep you all posted. Nevertheless, it isn't a huge deal if download progress and a status message aren't shown.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's put it this way...I sort of figured out my problem. At the end of my JavaScript function, I had `return true;` when it should be `return false;` so as to prevent a postback in my ASP.NET web form - postbacks/submit behaviors are prevented when putting the `return` keyword before the JavaScript function call on the button click and then having `return false;` at the bottom of the function. When I had it set to `return true`, the page actually didn't reload, but instead would skip the JavaScript and jump right to the C# to ask the user to open or save the file. With `return` set to `false` there was still no form submission as expected, but the download progress and status message actually would work on Firefox. Lucky for me, I can go 2-for-2 on this because I also have a "Save File to PC" link as one of the options in each row of the table, so the user could download the program that way. Yet, I wouldn't consider this case solved, as I only go 1-for-2 (JavaScript working and actual download through C# working) in my question's context.